# inverse of density function and P(Y<a) = a?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have found this problem to find the inverse probability density function.

Let $Y = X^3$. Then $h(x) = x^3 = y$, and $h^{-1}(y) = y^{1/3} = x$.

Since
$F_Y (y) = P[Y ≤ y] = P[X^3 ≤ y] = P[X ≤ y^{1/3}] = y^{1/3}$

The density is
$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}y^{1/3} = (1/3)y^{−2/3}$

The part that I don't get is this: $P[X ≤ y^{1/3}] = y^{1/3}$ How that is equal and we don't know yet the density function $f_Y(y)$ so we can integrate it?

Also, if the following problem is to be solved like the above way, how would you do it?

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable defined over $[-1; 1]$ and $Y = X^2$. Determine the density of $f_Y(y)$

Answer (score 1):

Calculus is not required here.   This is a job for substitution.

You were given that $\mathsf P(X\leq a)=a\quad\big[0\leq a\leq 1\big]$.

Well, what happens when we substitute $y^{1/3}$ for $a$ ?$$\mathsf P(X\leq y^{1/3})=y^{1/3}\quad\big[0\leq y^{1/3}\leq 1\big]$$

---

The second problem is solved similarly.  However, *be aware* that every positive $Y$ has two square roots, one positive and one negative, and here $X$ may be either.
That is, the transformation folds the two halves of the support for the $X$ distribution together. $$X\in[-1..0)\cup[0..1]\implies X^2\in[0..1]$$

So $f_Y(y)= ...?$ when $f_X(x)= 1~\big[-1\leq x\leq 1\big]$

Comment: For the first, "You were given that " Who gave that? -- That was part of the solution. Exercise said nothing about that. I know P(X < a) is calculated through either a ready CDF or by integrating PDF, No?

Comment: This is where I am looking exactly: https://academic.csuohio.edu/bmargolius/homepage/courses/mth424/notes/transf.pdf [Example 1]

Comment: I see; that's definitely the textbook's fault.  They neglected to specify that the distribution for $X$ is uniformly distributed (over $[0..1]$), as it needs to be to justify that claim.

Comment: and if X is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$? Is it a property that then $p(X < a) = a$ ?

Comment: For all $a$ within that support, yes.  (Also $1$ for $a>1$, of course.)